# asp.net "Scriptreference Path" setting not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a webform page that makes use of a master page which contain several script references. For this particular page I have two  items that reference additional java script footable.js and footable.striping.js.
The webform named calandar1old.aspx is located in the root directory and runs fine using the two script files. I get a responsive gridview with alternating row highlights.

If I create the same webform several directories down from the root, the page will load but the  scripts (footable.js and footable.striping.js) do not run. The scripts should create a responsive gridview and alternating row highlights. I have tried changing the path reference in /JML/Infoleague/Calandar1.aspx file as follows:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Path="js-foo/footable.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/jml/infoleague/js-foo/footable.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="./jml/infoleague/js-foo/footable.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="../../js-foo/footable.js" />
```

Here is the pertinent information from the master file:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SiteMenuHeader.Master.vb" Inherits="CoWorkerTestJML.SiteMenuHeader" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="author" content="SemiColonWeb" />


<!-- ============================================
    Stylesheets
============================================= -->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400italic|Open+Sans:400,300,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" type="text/css" href="css/retina.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors.php" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tipsy.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ls/css/layerslider.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


<!-- ============================================
    External JavaScripts
============================================= -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/layerslider.transitions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.layerslider.js"></script>
```

Here is the pertinent information from the /JML/Infoleague/Calandar1.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/SiteMenuHeader.Master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Calandar1.aspx.vb" Inherits="CoWorkerTestJML.JML_InfoLeague_Calandar1"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<meta name="viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css-foo/footable.core.css" type="text/css" />

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
<Scripts>
<asp:ScriptReference Path="../../js-foo/footable.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="js-foo/footable.striping.js" />
</Scripts>
```

I am almost positive that there is a path issue. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following path

```
<asp:ScriptReference Path="/js-foo/footable.js" />
```

...where the represented path is from the root of the site.
You could do the same with each of your CSS paths as well.